# MySQL query for last rows that have a specific field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a this table:

```
posts
id    | msg        | topicId
 1    | Hello World| 1
 2    | Whats up?  | 2
 3    | lorem ipsum| 1
 4    | new Topic  | 3
 5    | Dolor sit  | 1
 6    | some text  | 3
 7    | response   | 2
 8    | asdf       | 3
```

I want to get the row with the biggest `id` for every `topicId` like this:

```
result
id    | msg        | topicId
 5    | Dolor sit  | 1
 7    | response   | 2
 8    | asdf       | 3
```

My problem is I don't have a clue how to query for the result I want.
I'm using symfony 2.3 and doctrine, so if you could use the doctrine query builder code for the answer that would be great :)

Any idea to do this efficiently?

Comment: The duplicate question shows how to do it with regular MySQL. I don't know Doctrine, but you should be able to translate the solutions there. You can also search SO for `[mysql] [greatest-n-per-group]`, maybe some of the other questions use Doctrine. This is an EXTREMELY common question.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I didn't know what to search for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM YourTable T1
    LEFT JOIN YourTable T2 ON (T1.id= T2.id AND T1.TopicId < T2.TopicId)
WHERE T2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly! Now I just need to do this in doctrine query builder :)

Comment: i dont know how this solved your issue by the way , it will give unknown table m1 and even if you change it to t1 it will give all rows [look here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff4914/4)

Answer (score 2):

this a way to go

```
SELECT
posts.*
FROM
posts
JOIN (
SELECT MAX(id) AS id ,`msg`  , topicId
FROM posts 
GROUP BY `topicId`
) maxid

 ON posts.`topicId` = maxid.`topicId` 
    AND posts.id = maxid.id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff4914/2)